# Obfuscate a mysql query result for a string

Tags: php, mysql

I need to do something rather strange in MySQL, and I'm hoping to get some ideas on how to go about doing it in a query rather than post-processing the query results.

I have a field in the database that in some cases I need to return the value and in some cases, I don't want the value to be shown.  Because of a variety of reasons, I can't simply remove the field from the query when I don't want the value to be shown.  I need to obfuscate it - either by blanking it out, or replacing it with # signs, etc.

With dates, I can use DATE_FORMAT to return the date in the desired format.  Is there any kind of function I can do in MySQL that will hide the results of the column for me?

Amy

Comment: this would work: `select REPLACE(field_name, field_name, 'xxx') from table_name where id = 1;` but I don't see the *point*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`IF` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) in your `SELECT` query.

In `IF()` you specify some conditions and then name it as a column name:

```
SELECT col1, col2, IF(5 > 6, col3, '') AS col3 FROM table
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has an IF:

```
IF(secure, '', field) as field
```